# Square Root of kernel function validity

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

If k1(x,z) and k2(x,z) are valid kernels, then is k(x,z) a valid kernel, where k(x,z) = sqrt(k1(x,z)k2(x,z))

Prove using mercers theorem